# Lab test result meaning

Tags: blood-tests, endocrinology, thyroid

Why in this lab test results the microsomal antibodies amount has less sign and thireoglobulin antibodies don't have this sign? I did not question it first but now I have suspicion may be I am not getting it correctly. There is some ambiguity. [image: lab test results for thyroid gland disfunction]

Comment: The image you posted is too low resolution to read. In any case, we can't interpret lab results for you. Only your doctor can do that since he/she knows your medical history and why the tests were done in the first place.

Comment: @CareyGregory Question was about not interpreting results but about lab test results generally,what they mean when they write or not certain signs with results.I've re uploaded with better resolution.

Comment: Okay, much better now, and I guess I misinterpreted the intent of your question.

Answer (score 4):

Measurements will always have measurement errors, we distinguish between systematic errors and statistical errors due to noise, or other random effects than on average are zero. Usually the former type of error should not be in play, the tests will have been designed such that on average the tests results are correct. The latter type of error is always in play, this leads to an error margin that typically gets worse at lower measured values. This means that there will always exist a lowest cutoff value such that measurement values below it will be consistent with a real value ranging from zero up to the cutoff. This will then be reported like your value for the microsomal antibodies. For values that are a bit higher than the cutoff, the protocol will be to report the measured value, but the measurement error may still be significant.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that given the normal range of <34 (ie less than 34), a result of <5 (ie less than 5) is within normal range, because any number less than 5 is also less than 34.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular :-) obviously. Why they did not write less sign on thyreoglobulin  14. It could be <14.